# Decimal rounding behavior differs between Prod and Dev (SSIS Package)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I've a SSIS Package which calculates Rate and RateIns.

When I run this in DEV environment, Rate=1.3850588235, RateIns=1.138941176**5**

However, when I run this in Prod environment, Rate=1.3850588235, RateIns=1.138941176**4**

I tried to mimic SSIS logic in SSMS and code is below:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(
GST [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
[GSTFin] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
[GSTExl] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
[Rate] [decimal](18, 10) NULL,
[RateIns] [decimal](18, 10) NULL
)
insert into #temp values (11773.00,2092.00,8500.00,0,0)
UPDATE #TEMP
SET Rate=ISNULL(GST,0)/ISNULL(GSTExl,0)
,RateIns=(ISNULL(GST,0) - ISNULL(GSTFin,0))/ISNULL(GSTExl,0) 

SELECT * FROM #temp
DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

Result: Both DEV & Prod show same values:
Rate=1.3850588235, RateIns=1.1389411765

This confirmed that, issue is in SSIS package.
I compared metadata of components in both Prod and Dev packages. All match.
In fact, its the same SSIS package which has been deployed to Prod!

I wonder, why Prod SSIS package is showing RateIns=1.1389411764

Any suggestions?

Comment: Its not your package. It has something to do with decimal data type. Somebody had explained this earlier on SO, unfortunately I can't find the thread right now.

Comment: Thank you Prabhat. Any hint to search it in google? I tried browsing on this topic, but of no avail.

Comment: Cheers ! I found it on SO again. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44918488/difference-when-casting-a-datetime-to-a-decimal-on-different-sql-servers/44919027#44919027

Answer (score 0):

This might be a stupid question but is the hardware the same in prod versus dev. It's easy for different machines to give different results for floating point math. Maybe you could do that math based on  IEEE 754 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754 rules and see if at least one environment is giving the correct results.

Here's an online ieee754 calculator also
http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/

Comment: Hi Shawn, Thank you for your thoughts. Yes, hardware is similar in both servers (RAM/SSD/CPU). Not sure, if you meant other than these 3. About ieee754 calculator -> I'm confused on how to use it. Should I run the calculation in both servers, and try to match that with calculator value?

Comment: The only things that should cause a difference are the CPU and the OS/software,  If two systems are giving different results I would suggest that if you know what the inputs are to do the math manually using the IEEE-754 spec or one of the calculators and compare the results with the two systems and seeing one or possible both are going unexpected values. This all assumes that the systems are compliant with ieee754. Conversions to and from  divisions/multiplication of very real numbers can cause issues (http://wiki.seas.harvard.edu/geos-chem/index.php/Floating_point_math_issues)